# ¿Cómo gestionar la concurrencia para mostrar datos de sensores en una GUI?

Tags: python, hilos, pyqt5, networking, asyncio

Estoy trabajando en una interfaz de usuario con PyQt5 que se ocupará entre otras cosas de graficar datos de unos sensores. Recibo los datos mediante una comunicación CoAP y no se cuál sería la forma más eficiente de gestionar esos datos.

A través de una aplicación del fabricante, puedo recibir la información enviando mensajes tipo GET mediante protocolo CoAP. que me devuelven el dato que necesito. Por ejemplo:

```
def getSubState(channel):
 channel = str(channel)
 response = client.get("/state/sub?uc="+channel)
 return response.payload
```

He estado haciendo pruebas y he empezado a tener problemas al intentar integrar estos datos en la GUI. Por ejemplo, cuando intento que un label muestre continuamente un dato variable actualizado. he empezado con:

```
def getPressure(self):
self.inr=imb.getInletPressure(1)
self.label_inr.setText(str(self.inr))
```

Pero no se de que manera proceder para mantener el dato actualizado. He probado con un bucle *while True* pero empieza fallar. Creo que es un problema de concurrencia. Soy un programador novato y he estado viendo un poco por encima y veo que hay varias maneras de gestionar esto: Threads, AsyncIO, concurrent.futures ...etc

Mi pregunta es:

*¿Cuál es la forma más correcta de gestionar la concurrencia en este caso?*